# Dynamic content loads into jQuery qtip in all browsers except IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dynamic-data, qtip

qTip...a jQuery custom tooltip plugin... isn't loading dynamic content for IE8 (haven't tested in IE6/7).  qTip initializes but no content (text) loads into it.

Here is my code:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                var errorcontent=eval(error);

                element.parents('.rightfields').find('.norederrorx').removeClass('norederrorx').addClass('rederrorx').qtip(
                {
                    show: {when: 'mouseover', solo: true},
                    content: { text: errorcontent },
                    //formatting options here
                    }
                });
```

So yea...  content: { text:errorcontent } loads none of the `errorcontent` :(

I've tried also `content: errorcontent,`

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Emile

Comment: So a jQuery plugin doesn't work the way you expect in IE. Wouldn't it be best to seek help in the forum for that plugin? http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/forum-qtip-1-x

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I looked on there before I came here.  Stack is a much faster way to get help but I can understand that it's probably best to keep the discussions consolidated to their groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quoting when:

```
show: {'when': 'mouseover' }
```

It's probably a special keyword in IE. Also, what did you try to debug so far with `alert`?

Comment: Both the alert debugging idea/reminder and the IE special keyword came in useful for me.  It's was a trifecta solution for me...the last piece being to change "errorcontent" to "errorcontent.text()"  Thanks for your help meder!